# passing data from controller to blade view laravel Undefined Variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

Hello i try to display data from my controller to laravel view im got undefined variable error" my controller

```
 public function courseDetails($slug, Request $request)
{

    try {
        $is_cart = 0;
        $course = Course::with('enrollUsers', 'user', 'user.courses', 'user.courses.enrollUsers', 'user.courses.lessons', 'chapters.lessons', 'enrolls', 'lessons', 'reviews', 'chapters', 'activeReviews')
            ->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        if (!$course) {
            Toastr::error(trans('common.Operation failed'), trans('common.Failed'));
            return redirect()->back();
        }
```

my blade.php

```
@elseif(routeIs('courseDetailsView'))

    <meta itemprop="description" content="{{ $course->meta_description  }}">

    <meta property="og:description" content="{{ $course->meta_description  }}">

    <meta itemprop="keywords" content="{{ $course->meta_keywords }}">

@elseif(routeIs('quizDetailsView'))

    <meta itemprop="description" content="{{ $course->meta_description  }}">

    <meta property="og:description" content="{{ $course->meta_description  }}">

    <meta itemprop="keywords" content="{{ $course->meta_keywords }}">

@endif
```

Error

> ErrorException
> Undefined variable: course (View: /var/www/aplication_work/resources/views/frontend/theme/partials/_header.blade.php)

Comment: Where exactly do you return/pass data to your view?

Comment: Where are you even loading/rendering the view?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are not passing your `$course` variable to your blade view yet. Try using the following.

```
return view('your view',['course'=>$course]);
```